# How to make an HTTP request in PHP?

Tags: php, http, request, sms, httprequest

I have to send an SMS by making an HTTP request via GET method. The link contains information in the form of GET variables, e.g.

```
http://www.somelink.com/file.php?from=12345&to=67890&message=hello%20there
```

After I run the script it has to be as if someone clicked the link and activated the SMS sending process.

I have found some links about get request and curl and what not, it’s all so confusing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use cURL.  See https://web.archive.org/web/20180819060003/http://codular.com/curl-with-php for some examples.

Comment: Not the easiest way but it sure is fun. I couldn't get it to work cause I didn't do sudo apt-get install php5-curl in the Terminal first. :)

Answer (score 12):

I think the easiest way to make an HTTP request via GET method from PHP is using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

```
<?php
$response = file_get_contents('http://example.com/send-sms?from=12345&to=67890&message=hello%20there');
echo $response;
```

Don’t forget to see the [notes section](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#refsect1-function.file-get-contents-notes) for info on PHP configuration required for this to work. You need to set `allow_url_fopen` to true in your `php.ini`.

Note that this works for GET requests only and that you will have no access to the headers (request, nor response). Also, enabling `allow_url_fopen` might not be a good choice for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume that we want to retrive http://www.google.com

```
$cURL = curl_init();
$setopt_array = array(CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.google.com",    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array()); 
curl_setopt_array($cURL, $setopt_array);
$json_response_data = curl_exec($cURL);
print_r($json_response_data);
curl_close($cURL);
```

/*
   cURL is preinstalled by goDaddy.com and many other php hosting providers
   it is also preinstalled in wamp and xampp
   good luck.
*/